Proof verification and hint request for HoTT book exercise 2.17
Exercise 2.17.
(i) Show that if $A \simeq A'$ and $B \simeq B'$, then $(A \times B) \simeq (A' \times B')$.
(ii) Give two proofs of this fact, one using univalence and one not using it, and show that the two proofs are equal.
Solution attempted:
(1) Given $(f:A \to A', \mathrm{isequiv}(f)) : A \simeq A'$ and $(g:B \to B', \mathrm{isequiv}(g)) : B \simeq B'$, by the univalence axiom, we can get $A=A'$ and $B=B'$. Then we can use pair to get $A \times A'=B\times B'$, then we can use idtoeq to get $A \times A'\simeq B \times B'$.
(2) Stuck, would like a hint.
Potential problems with solution: I haven't learned Agda or Coq yet, so I'm not sure how to check it by machine; but I think some problems with this solution would be using pair on types instead of on terms. Is this justified? Obviously I would have to formulate it and prove it, but does this work?

What do you mean by "using pair"? You should clarify what principle you are appealing to exactly. As for (2), just let the type guide you: in order to construct an equivalence $A \times A' \simeq B \times B'$, you need to give a function $A \times A' \to B \times B'$ such that ...

Pair, in the case of terms is the canonical map $(\text{pr}_1(x) =_A \text{pr}_1(y)) \times (\text{pr}_2(x) =_B \text{pr}2(y)) \rightarrow (x ={A \times B} y) $.

Okay, so you can apply that to get an identity $(A, A') = (B, B')$. What now? You need $A \times A' = B \times B'$.

Would using path induction work in this case? Or should i just define a function  from (A=A') X (B=B') to (A x A'= B x B') explicitly?  Thank you

You can of course define this function directly by path induction, or you can use $\mathrm{ap}_\times$ (from section 2.2), considering $\times$ as a function $\mathcal{U} \times \mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{U}$.

(2) is essentially asking you to construct the equivalence directly. Given maps $A \to A'$ and $B \to B'$, can you construct a map $A \times B \to A' \times B'$? Then, in the case the aforementioned maps are equivalences, you can show that the map you constructed is also an equivalence.

@IsAdisplayName  It would just be the map  from   the universal property of cartesian product, right?

@Frog2341 pretty, much. That is hows its defined. Its the map from the functorial action on maps of the cartesian product.
